# How to create new syntax block for try with finally?

Tags: syntax, exception, f#

I really often use:

```
try
  try
  with
finally
```

so I'm interesting if is possible to make new syntax operator to not write "try" two times.

```
let mytry foo bar foobar =
  try 
    try 
      foo
    with 
      | _ -> bar // weird part here, I want to have a match
  finally foobar

mytry 
  <| foo
  <| | :? SocketException -> 
     | _ -> // ok it looks funny but how to realize it?
  <| foobar
```

the problems I see here are

- non-common syntax, in mytry there is no try with finally keywords, just <| <| <| for each, but it's lesser trouble I guess
- with: I don't know how can I realize this part. even how it will look if I can realize it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is whether you really need `try/finally`. Most of the time `try/finally` is used for disposing resources even when exceptions occur. But you can always replace it by the `use` keyword.

For example:

```
open System.IO

let openFile(url: string) =
    let fileStream = File.OpenText(url)
    try
        try
          let readline = fileStream.ReadLine()
          printfn "Readline: %s" readline
        with
            | :? IOException as ex -> 
                     printfn "IOException: %A" ex
            | ex ->  printfn "Another exception: %A" ex
    finally
        fileStream.Dispose()
```

can be rewritten as:

```
let openFile(url: string) =
    use fileStream = File.OpenText(url)
    try
        let readline = fileStream.ReadLine()
        printfn "Readline: %s" readline
    with
        | :? IOException as ex -> 
                 printfn "IOException: %A" ex
        | ex ->  printfn "Another exception: %A" ex
```

For the learning purpose, you can define `mytry` using high-order functions as follows:

```
let mytry foo bar foobar =
  try 
    try 
      foo ()
    with 
      | exn -> bar exn
  finally foobar ()
```

But it doesn't look really nice on above example:

```
let myOpenFile(url: string) =
    let fileStream = File.OpenText(url)
    mytry (fun () -> let readline = fileStream.ReadLine()
                     printfn "Readline: %s" readline)
          (fun ex -> match ex with
                     | :? IOException -> 
                            printfn "IOException: %A" ex
                     | _ -> printfn "Another exception: %A" ex)
          (fun () -> fileStream.Dispose())
```

Comment: Why, I like the look! And I've got really complex logic where I need it, it's not just use it's even about speaking with other applications. Maybe I can avoid it but try/with/finally is easiest solution I found there.

Comment: Yes, it depends on one's preference. I prefer explicit `try/with/finally` to `mytry` if I do not have to use them too often.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a higher-order function that takes the three parts as separate function. The body of the `try` would be a function `unit -> 'R` where `'R` is the result. The exception handler will need to handle only some exceptions, so you can return `option` to say whether you handled the result or if you want the exception to be rethrown. The type of handler will be `exn -> 'R option`. The finalizer is then simply a function `unit -> unit`.

The usage is not as elegant as using built-in language feature, but it does the trick:

```
tryWithFinally 
  (fun () ->
    1/0 )                                 // The nested body 
  (function
    | :? DivideByZeroException -> Some -1 // Handle division by zero
    | _ -> None )                         // Rethrow any other exceptions
  (fun () -> 
    printfn "done" )
```

The implementation is quite easy once you know the structure, but for completeness, here it is:

```
let tryWithFinally f handler finalizer =
  try
    try f()
    with e -> 
      match handler e with
      | Some r -> r
      | None -> reraise()
  finally
    finalizer()
```

Anyway, I agree with @pad that in most of the cases, you should be fine with just `use` and `try .. with`.